# Angular 6 router resolve - Component not being called

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angular6

Following is my resolve which I have defined on a route.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CourseDetailResover implements Resolve<Observable<[Course, (Lesson[])]>>  {

    constructor(private coursesService: CoursesService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<[Course, (Lesson[])]> {
            return this.coursesService.findCourseByUrl(route.params['id'])
            .pipe(
                tap(data => console.log(data)),
                switchMap(
                    course => this.coursesService.findLessonsForCourse(course.id)
                        .pipe(
                             tap(data => console.log(data)),
                            map<Lesson[], [Course, Lesson[]]>(lessons => [course, lessons]),
                            tap(data => console.log(data))
                        )
                )
            );
    }
}
```

My Route is

```
  {
        path: 'course/:id',
        component: CourseDetailComponent,
        resolve: {
            detail:CourseDetailResover
        }
    }
```

I am finding that even though the resolver is being invoked the component ngOnInit below is never actually invoked

```
export class CourseDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  course$: Observable<Course>;
  lessons$:Observable<Lesson[]>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('inside here');
    this.course$ = this.route.data.pipe(map(data => data['detail'][0]));

    this.lessons$ = this.route.data.pipe(map(data => data['detail'][1]));
  }
}
```

On enabling tracing on the route I can see that the following.

```
Router Event: ResolveStart
```

However there is no `Router Event: ResolveEnd` present in the trace logs.

What could be the issue here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are double nesting RxJS `observables` here - it that intended? When looking at the `Resolve` interface of angular, you are implementing it right, but your `T` is actually an `Observable` itself:

```
export interface Resolve<T> {
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<T> | Promise<T> | T;
}
```

So your resolver class should look similar to this:

```
export class CourseDetailResover implements Resolve<[Course, (Lesson[])]>
```

The fact that your `ngOnInit` is never called, leads to the assumption that the `Observable` returned by your `resolve` method never terminates / completes. Note that the Observable has to complete in order for the resolver to "conclude" its work and continue with the routing process. Have a look at this issue for reference:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10556

Following code will work

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CourseDetailResover implements Resolve<Promise<Observable<[Course, (Lesson[])]>>>  {

    constructor(private coursesService: CoursesService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<Observable<[Course, (Lesson[])]>> {
            const routerObservable =   this.coursesService.findCourseByUrl(route.params['id'])
            .pipe(
                switchMap(
                    course => this.coursesService.findLessonsForCourse(course.id)
                        .pipe(
                            map<Lesson[], [Course, Lesson[]]>(lessons => [course, lessons]),
                        )
                )
            );

            return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                routerObservable.pipe(
                    first()
                ).subscribe((data) => {
                    console.log(data)
                    resolve(routerObservable)});
            })
    }
}
```

On the component side

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('inside here');
     const observableD:Observable<[Course, (Lesson[])]> = this.route.snapshot.data["detail"];
    this.course$ = observableD.pipe(
      map(data => data[0])
    );

    this.lessons$ = observableD.pipe(
      map(data => data[1])
    );
  }
```